# Unable to link from one app to the another

Tags: django

I am trying to route from app Home to app Services using the following :

```
<li><a href="{% url 'services.index' %}">Our Services</a></li>
```

Services app:

urls.py for services app

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

view

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.http import  HttpResponse


def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'services/index.html', context)
```

urls.py for the site:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('services/', include('services.urls'), name = 'services'),
    path('home/', include('home.urls'), name = 'home'),
]
```

Unfortunately I get error as:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'services.index' not found. 'services.index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

In settings.py I have set the app in INSTALLED_APPS and also set templates folder for it.

When visiting

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/services/
```

it works totally fine.

**Edit : Adding colon instead of dot as:**

```
<li><a href="{% url 'services:index' %}">Our Services</a></li>
```

it threw the errors:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
'services' is not a registered namespace
```

Comment: please write your urls.py principal

Comment: @Tegito123, done. please check

Comment: try `{% url 'services:index' %}"` instead

Comment: It's `{% url 'services:index' %}`. Colon not dot.

Comment: also it might be worth specifying `app_name='<my_app_name>'` in `services/urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

first you need setup you urls.py principal:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('services/', include('services.urls', namespace = 'services')),
    path('home/', include('home.urls', namespace = 'home')),
]
```

in this case only change **name** by **namespace**
second is your urls.py from your app:

```
from django.urls import path

    from services.views import index

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', index, name='index')
    ]
```

on your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'services:index' %}">My Index</a>
```

Comment: These gave me so many errors. Oh God.   .... nf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.